# Creating a regex to only accept a specific set of strings

Tags: regex

I need to have a REGEX that would filter out and only accept a certain groups of string, or in my case, codes.

This is what I have, and it works but doesn't seem like the smartest way to doing this.

```
/^[046R,047R,048R,049R,050R,051R\ ]+$/
```

Now, the list of codes that I can accept are anywhere from '046R' to '089R' (the 046 to 089 are sequential). So I can keep explicitly writing all the codes accepted on my expression (as I started above) but there is a better way for sure.
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranges to the rescue:

```
/^(04[6-9]R|0[5-8][0-9]R) +$/
```

Live example: http://www.rubular.com/r/Bfnm4Tj7hT

Answer (score 2):

```
^0(?:4[6-9]|[5-8]\d)R$
```

Should do the trick. You have to set exclusive on 04x, but 5-8x is pretty generic.

**[Demo](http://regexr.com?2t9ms)**

For capturing, surround in parenthesis:

```
^(0(?:4[6-9]|[5-8]\d)R)$
```